# creating table and checking table exits in same function not working in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

While going to model the tables are created but the second function the file exits is not working

#### controller

```
public function harsha() {
    $this->model->function1();
    echo $this->model->function2(); //it showing false instated of true
}
```

#### model

```
public function function1() {
    $this->db->query("create table some xxx"); //table created successfully on database 
}
public function function2() {
    return $this->db->table_exists("xxx"); //but it's returning false;
}
```

Comment: Is this your code or you are just explaining us, can you share your actual code?

Comment: by using controller  harsha() function  i am calling to model function and creating one sql table dynamically, and  the table is created in the database after that it returned to same controller , then again am calling another function in the same model and i trying to check weather table exits are not but it returning false ,but the table is created in the database and i am trying to get data from the table by using select function i am able to get the data, only file exists functions is not working in continuous controller function

Answer (score 0):

While creating table there should be atleast one field name. In the function2() I kept if condition, if table exists it returns true else it returns false. The following below code works fine.

```
public function function1() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE xxx (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL )";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}

public function function2() {
    if($this->db->table_exists("xxx")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: To create a table you need to give some column name like this: CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name column_type);

Comment: $this->db->table_exists("xxx"); will return false only, i am explaining structure i know for creating table atlest one filled is required and i now if condition is required for   $this->db->table_exists() function. please check var_dump($this->db->table_exists("xxx")); the table is creating on database but it showing false on var_dump($this->db->table_exists("xxx"));  note: please use only one controller function and two  model functions